# What are correct SublimeVideo settings using it with Heroku and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, html5-video

I'm trying to use www.sublimevideo.net to stream video for a Rails app on www.heroku.com. It provides me with a customised embed code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/w3ox3zfc.js"></script>
```

All of this works fine with local testing, but fails when I run the site off Heroku.

When I click to run the player, I get a dialog:

```
SublimeVideo Player is not properly registered for this site.
Learn more at: http://cl.ly/94xM
```

My settings:

- **Add your domain or subdomain:** *myapp.herokuapp.com*
- **Staging and alias domains:** *[blank]*
- **Development domains:** *127.0.0.1, localhost*
- **Advanced settings:** *[blank]*
- **Wildcard (*.yourdomain.com)** *[blank]*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just following up on this:

Spoke with SublimeVideo support who suggested clearing the cache, which seemed to work.